# sshpass does not work. Is there an alternative?

Tags: linux, ssh, password

I use a small programm = sshpass 
to use ssh  in a script to execute commands on linux routers

Is there a alternative to sshpass
because sshpass works at the moment not correctly (Bugs) -  incompatibilities with the sshclient

Answer (score 3):

It didn't look like anyone mentioned expect yet: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: Similar and maybe easier `python-pexpect` and `expect4j` available too, you have my upvote either. Yours might be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is its alternative available:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script

but this is NEVER recommended as it is a serious security weakness and can lead your system open to anyone.
better to setup password-less ssh login to the machines on which you want to run specific commands.

Comment: it not work because the --stdin works only with passwd not with ssh  it gives an error. i know the security weakness but the client and the router are in a vpn network and nobody from outsite can access to this clients.

Comment: what about keyless ssh authentication? isnt that possible?

Comment: sadly not because the root system is read only and a cant send a key file to this system. I will write a small script was execute a script to update the router configuration over ssh

Comment: then --stdin would work for you as mentioned in the link i gave.

Comment: ssh got no option --stdin   when i test it i got an error :  Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.